# ElasticSearch Filtered Subdocument Count

Tags: elasticsearch

I'd like to count the number of devices having greater than two sessions in a date range.

Given the elastic search document and subdocument array below as an example:

```
{
  "_index": "device",
  "_type": "device_type",
  "_id": "5ee1a8a2fde077a42e144a1425b6d501",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "sessions": [
      {
        "sessionIdentifier": "bfa369ca-2ed7-4ccd-adc6-3cc0768e6264",
        "sessionStartTime": "1399672448000"
      },
      {
        "sessionIdentifier": "22886451-5b0d-4c25-9dac-38a7f4596f67",
        "sessionStartTime": "1399672449000"
      },
      {
        "sessionIdentifier": "adab71cf-1d32-444c-8931-4783b8813f74",
        "sessionStartTime": "1399672500000"
      }
    ],
    "numSessions": 3,
    "deviceIdentifier": "5ee1a8a2fde077a42e144a1425b6d501"
  }
}
```

a "hit" for date ranges such as:

1. 1399672448000 <= date <= 1399672500000 (3 sessions)
2. 1399672448000 <= date <= 1399672449000 (2 sessions)

and a "miss" for date ranges such as:

1. 1399672448000 <= date < 1399672449000 (1 session)

Is there a performant way to accomplish this query for arbitrarily large date ranges using elastic search? I am not opposed to further denormalization of the data or any alternative suggestions.